# How I can give the effect of a button to an ImageView when I click?

Tags: android, imageview, android-button

For many reasons I had to define an ImageView as button, because it looks better. But when I click on it doesn't have the button's effect, How do I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about the onClick method or the visual pressed state?

Comment: use an ImageButton, it extends ImageView and yes its clickable

Comment: @pskink I can't use that coz mthe image is dropped.

Comment: @zhelon what you mean by "image is dropped"?

Comment: @pskink misconfigured (google traslate suck)

Comment: misconfigured??? it means...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a `selector` as the background, however is is much better to use an `ImageButton` since it was essentially design to do just that.

FYI here is the style definition of ImageButton

```
<style name="Widget.ImageButton">
     <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
     <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
     <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same request a couple of days ago. Here is my solution with **animations** and **vibration**.

In ressource files, create 2 files:
   res/anim/**anim_scale_down.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"  
    android:fillAfter="true"  
    android:fillEnabled="true">  
   <scale  
       android:fromXScale="1"  
       android:toXScale="0.95"  
       android:fromYScale="1"  
       android:toYScale="0.95"  
       android:pivotX="50%"  
       android:pivotY="50%"  
       android:duration="100"        
  />  
  </set>
```

and res/anim/**anim_scale_up.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">  
   <scale  
       android:fromXScale="0.95"  
       android:toXScale="1"  
       android:fromYScale="0.95"  
       android:toYScale="1"  
       android:pivotX="50%"  
       android:pivotY="50%"  
       android:duration="50"  
  />  
</set>
```

In your activity, declare 2 animations as members:

```
 private Animation _animUp;
 private Animation _animDown;
```

In `onCreate`, set the members with animations resources:

```
_animDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_context, R.anim.anim_scale_down);
_animUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_context, R.anim.anim_scale_up);
```

then declare an onTouchListener:

```
private View.OnTouchListener _animListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {

                case (android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                    view.startAnimation(_animDown);
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator)_context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(25);
                    return false;
                case (android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    view.startAnimation(_animUp);
                    return false;
                case (android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
                    view.startAnimation(_animUp);

                    }
            return false;
        }       
    };
```

Set the touchListener to your button:

```
 myButton.setOnTouchListener(_animListener);
```

Don't forget to set the vibrate permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: graet solution. I prefer it respect to the selector

Comment: Great solution, thanks, but how to know if the system vibration is enabled or not? in other words, I want to play the vibration if it's enabled by system.

Comment: If vibration is not activated or if the device doesn't have a vibration module, this code works fine. I've tried it on a Nexus 7.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a 'pressed' visual state to an `ImageView`, use a `selector` as a drawable.

In your drawables folder, create a new xml file as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/myDrawable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/myPressedDrawable" />
</selector>
```

Setting the above drawable as the image source will display 'myDrawable' as the default image, and 'myPressedDrawable' when the user is pressing on the view.

Comment: @Yjvay I dont undestand the last paragraph "Setting the above drawable as the image source will display 'myDrawable' as the default image, and 'myPressedDrawable' when the user is pressing on the view."